# XML Parsing using C#

Tags: c#, xml

in my XML String

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>neighborhood</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Phase 1, Sector 57, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Phase 1</long_name>
            <short_name>Phase 1</short_name>
            <type>neighborhood</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <place_id>ChIJDTCn80PuDzkRFK0l5i2S0iQ</place_id>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

how can i just find `formatted_address` value from the entire xml. I need to find it using C#.net

Comment: Use Linq to XML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using XmlDocument:

```
string s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\"?><GeocodeResponse><status>OK</status><result><type>neighborhood</type><type>political</type><formatted_address>Phase 1, Sector 57, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India</formatted_address><address_component><long_name>Phase 1</long_name><short_name>Phase 1</short_name><type>neighborhood</type><type>political</type></address_component><place_id>ChIJDTCn80PuDzkRFK0l5i2S0iQ</place_id></result></GeocodeResponse>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(s);
var elmts = doc.GetElementsByTagName("formatted_address");
if (elmts.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(elmts[0].InnerText); // will show "Phase 1, Sector 57, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XDcoument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) for it, to parse the xml string in to `XDocument` object, then call [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) by sepcifying element name which you want to find, in this case **"formatted_address"**:

```
string MyXml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>neighborhood</type>
        <type>political</type>
        <formatted_address>Phase 1, Sector 57, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India</formatted_address>
        <address_component>
            <long_name>Phase 1</long_name>
            <short_name>Phase 1</short_name>
            <type>neighborhood</type>
            <type>political</type>
        </address_component>
        <place_id>ChIJDTCn80PuDzkRFK0l5i2S0iQ</place_id>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>";

XDocument XDocument = XDocument.Parse(MyXml);

var Filtered =XDocument.Descendants("formatted_address").FirstOrDefault();


if(Filtered !=null)
    Console.WriteLine("formatted_address: "+Filtered.Value);
```

[Working Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U8hwfD)

Answer (score 0):

Although you shouldn't use regex for parsing XML, since you are only interested in one node, a regex will be a simpler and faster solution than parsing the entire document.

Try this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var xmlString = "<formatted_address>Phase 1, Sector 57, Sahibzada Ajit Singh Nagar, Punjab, India</formatted_address>";
var match = Regex.Match(xmlString, @"<(formatted_address>)(.+?)<\/\1");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
```